# Can I somehow reinstate the file name on a 'file' type input if the page post fails?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload

Often some validation factor with nothing to with the file will cause a server side validation error, and reload the page. The previously chosen filename is always missing, and the poor user has to select the file again. This is especially frustrating when they fix the other error and click Submit again, thinking all will be all right.

Can I not somehow persist the file name in my model and set it on the 'file' input when the page loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every form submission requires complete file upload, so to not make user poor, you should store file on server even when validation fails. When you do it, you have list of already uploaded files on the server ready for next, proper form submission. You can also present box with already uploaded files in view.

For security reasons, manipulating file upload field is not possible.